# Searching in a large html list with more than 6000 list items

Tags: jquery, html, list, search, listjs

I have a large html list in the below format. The html page size is 6 mb and there are more than 6000 list items. I want to add search and sorting functionality to it. I tried [list.js](http://listjs.com/), it is working perfectly with less list items but when I am loading it with the 6 MB html list the browser is crashing and taking around 3 to 4 minutes for first load offline. How can I add search in this large list ?

```
<li> <p class="vs" id="list1">
  &nbsp;content from list one 
</li>

<li> <p class="vs" id="list2">
  &nbsp;content from list two 
</li>

<li> <p class="vs" id="list3">
  &nbsp;content from list three
</li>

<li> <p class="vs" id="list4">
  &nbsp;content from list four
</li>
```

Comment: Sir I would suggest considering `Pagination`.

Comment: Pagination and server search

Comment: if i paginate the list will it solve the lag problems ??

Comment: what code should i put to get it done ?

Comment: code to do pagination and sorting at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Cache all items into an object first:

```
var abbrs = {};

$("ul#abbreviations li").each(function (i) {
    abbrs[this.firstChild.nodeValue] = this;
});
```

Then look for the typed text in your object:

```
var li = abbrs[this.value.toUpperCase()];
// show li, hide others
```

Update: For partial matches, you'd have to iterate through the collection:

```
var filterBy = this.value.toUpperCase();

for (var abbr in abbrs) {
    if (abbr.indexOf(filterBy) !== -1) {
        var li = abbrs[abbr];
        // show li
    }
}
```